# Node JS, express-session удалить куки на клиенте

Tags: node.js, express-sessions

Уважаемые дамы и господа, доброго времени суток.

Работаю с приложением, которое уже имеет готовую инфраструктуру. Задача следующая: нужно не дать клиенту возможность залогиниться в нескольких браузерах. В рамках этой задачи я столкнулся с проблемой - не могу удалить куки для конкретного браузер.

I. Кратко:

Настройки следующие:

Сервер: nodeJS Порт: 8083

Клиент: VueJS Порт: 8088

Использую модуль `express-session` для инициализации механизма сессий на сервере и передачи куки на клиент.

II. Подробнее:

Корневой файл сервера - **index.js**

В нем выполняю следующее:

1. Подключаю модуль `express`:

```
const express = require('express')
```

2. Подключаю модуль `cors`:

```
const cors = require('cors')
```

3. Добавляю настройки `cors`:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8088',
    credentials: true
}))
```

В файле **user.js** инициализирую сессии и принимаю подключения от клиента:

1. Подключаю модуль `express-session`:

```
const session = require('express-session')
```

2. Настраиваю маршрутизацию через `express.Router()`:

```
const router = express.Router()
```

3. Произвожу настройки сессии:

```
const EIGHT_HOURS  = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8
const {
    SESS_NAME = 'sid',
    SESS_LIFETIME = EIGHT_HOURS,
    SESS_SECRET = 'test',
    NODE_ENV = 'development'
} = process.env
const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

4. Инициализирую сессию:

```
router.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: false,
        // Must have HTTPS to work 'secret:true'
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))
```

5. Принимаю запросы с клиента через `router.post()`

Выполняю следующие действия: используя `req.session.destroy`, я удаляю сессию, которая у меня есть на данный момент и ожидаю, что в браузере, где пользователь уже осуществил вход, разлогинит пользователя, в связи с тем, что очистятся куки:

```
req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })
```

Но чуда не происходит, к сожалению.

Лазил по форумам. Например, в этом ([GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/507)) есть подобный вопрос. Как вариант решения - в методе `res.clearCookie` использовать явное указание пути, по которому должны располагаться куки, то бишь `{path: '/'})`. Это не помогает. Прописывал данные путь в настройках куки, тоже не помогает:

```
router.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
    path: '/',
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: false,
        // Must have HTTPS to work 'secret:true'
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))
```

При том, что в документации к `express-session`([NPM:express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)) говорится, что путь `path: '/'` задан по умолчанию.

Пробовал пойти черзе `req.session = null` ([StackOverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573256/how-to-end-a-session-in-expressjs)), добавив в `req.session.destroy`:

```
req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
            req.session = null
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })
```

Но, как я понимаю, к моей теме это не относится, скорее справедливо для модуля cookie-session.

`delete req.session` тоже не выручает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как  можно решить данную проблему? Что я упускаю?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу тут попытки удалить сессию в другом браузере.

Comment: Так а как должно выглядеть удаление сессии, если не подобным образом: ````req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
            req.session = null
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })````

Comment: Т.е получается, что у меня в req.session сохраняется сессия пользователя, а после процедуры удаления, описанной выше (через `req.session.destroy`), сессия становится `undefined`. Таким образом я понимаю, что сессия удалилась. Другое дело, что, коли удалилась сессия, но куки не затерлись, то сама сессия возобновляется на браузере с точно таким же `sessionID`, как был раньше. Как я прочитал на форумах, такова механика работы механизма сессий. Соответственно, натуральным образом и в резкой форме встал вопрос, как мне удалить куки и что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

В настройках сессии надо прописать `unset: 'destroy'`

В итоге, инициализация сессии будет выглядеть вот так:

```
router.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: 'destroy',
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: false,
        // Must have HTTPS to work 'secret:true'
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))
```